# How should I organize a collection of Classes

Tags: oop, class, collections

I have a series of objects and each has meta-data associated with it. In the typical case, I have a class representing Object and Meta_Data and I can make Meta_Data an attribute of the Object.

```
+---------------+    +---------------+
|    Object     |--->|   Meta_Data   |
+---------------+    +---------------+
```

The issue arrises when I want to create a collection of Objects, each of which is associated with a particular instance of Meta_Data.

The Meta_Data needs to be able to access its own neighbors:

```
a[0] = Object();
a[1] = Object();

// a[0].meta needs to be able to interact with a[1].meta
a[0].meta = Meta_Data();
a[1].meta = Meta_Data();
```

If I just create a collection of Objects (with Meta_Data instances as attributes), then the Meta_Data instances are isolated and can only interact by going through the primary object. This seems less than ideal.

The only real alternative that I can think of is to create some container class that allows me to have:

1. An ObjectStack attribute that contains a collection of Object instances
2. A Meta_DataStack attribute that contains a collection of Meta_Data instances
3. Some sort of interface that syncs up the two so that I can query the corresponding meta-data for any particular Object instance.

This again seems inefficient. So what is the best way to have to collections of objects that can be linked item-by-item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have then is something like this:

```
[Object]--->[MetaData]<--+
                |        |
                +--------+
```

Something needs to be in charge of connecting the MetaData objects and it can't be any one particular Object object. You need a Factory or Builder of some sort that puts everything together properly.

That doesn't mean that the Factory needs to maintain a reference to every instance of both classes that exist, it just needs to make the connections.

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = new Object();
MetaData ma = new MetaData();
MetaData mb = new MetaData();

ma.setFriend(mb);
a.setMetaData(ma);
b.setMetaData(mb);
```